# Can't open java mind-mapping create from Freeplane

Tags: java

I've created mindmap in freeplane and then export it as "Java", that gave me a html file and a folder.

When I open this html file in windows it works correctly in Google Chrome and Firefox. But opening it in ubuntu, it's not working.

In Firefox, FF asked me to allow IcedTea plugin but even I allow it, it always cause my computer to crashed

In Chrome, it always redirects me to java download page

What should I do?

I saw some advice about running applet in "appletviewer" but I don't know how to install "appletviewer", either

Answer (score 0):

`appletviewer` is provided by the JDK packages. In Ubuntu 14.04, you can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Then open the HTML file using:

```
appletviewer /path/to/html/file
```

You can copy the path to the file from the browser's address bar.

Comment: It turns out to be like this

http://i1328.photobucket.com/albums/w525/siravac/snapshot4_zpsbbd5a979.png

What should I do?